# Efficient way to convert a 16-bit short array to a 32-bit int array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, copy

What is the most efficient way to convert an array of unsigned short numbers (16 bits per value) into an array of unsigned ints numbers (32 bits per value)?

Comment: Create a `int[]` and copy the shorts over?

Comment: There is no C/C++. Therefore some answers apply to C and others to C++.

Comment: If you can live with the `short`s and don't need to copy at all, that's **the most efficient way** :)

Comment: What CPU architecture and compiler are you using?

Comment: A short is not necessarily 16 bits, and an int is not necessarily 32 bits. This is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Peter, indeed, I've worked on platforms where unsigned short and unsigned int are the same type, and so the most efficient conversion is simply to do nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copy it.

```
unsigned short source[]; // …
unsigned int target[]; // …
unsigned short* const end = source + sizeof source / sizeof source[0];
std::copy(source, end, target);
```

[`std::copy`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) internally choses the best copying mechanism for given input types. In this case, however, there’s probably no better way than copying the elements individually in a loop.

Comment: @Dair This doesn’t fail – it definitely works. I’ve tested it.

Comment: Also you could use the `vector` `(iterator, iterator)` constructor.

Comment: I doubt that std::copy has internal mechanisms for handling short specifically? Most likely the shorts are promoted to ints, and then you've merely invented a way to copy ints to ints. Also, this will never be the most efficient way on many platforms, as it is forced to compare addresses instead of comparing a counter iterator against a fixed value.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, this will probably happen – and why not? Have you got a better idea? Then submit a patch to GCC. You’re right about the comparison though. But this already involves a lot of second-guessing, namely that a manual loop will be faster than `copy`. And in this case you may be right. In most cases you’d be wrong.

Comment: As a data point, a simple loop and `std::copy` both compile to the same  code with GCC 4.5.2 on my Core2Duo: A loop using `pmovsxwd` and `movdqu` with handling for any reamaing elements. (compiled with `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native`).

Comment: @Konrad I don't this this is a bug as such, but rather the way STL is specified in the standard.

Comment: With optimizations enabled this topic is pretty much pointless, yeah? Especially as they will vary on different compilers. For std::copy to be equally efficient as a loop, the function call has to be inlined, to begin with.

Comment: @Lundin “With optimizations enabled this topic is pretty much pointless, yeah?” – ***No*.** The opposite is the case. *Only* optimised code is worth talking about. C++ *relies* on code being optimised. Any discussion not accounting for this is moot. You already mentioned inlining – well, good, modern C++ code relies on such performance characteristics. We’re working on a library here which entirely relies on the ability of C++ compilers to handle abstraction well. And I’ve never implied that any behaviour is a bug. But if you know how to optimise a particular special case this is valuable.

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::copy` in C++:

```
#include<algorithm> //must include

unsigned short ushorts[M]; //where M is some const +ve integer
unsigned int   uints[N]; //where N >= M
//...fill ushorts
std::copy(ushorts, ushorts+M, uints);
```

And in C, use manual loop (in fact, you can use manual loop both in C and C++):

```
int i = 0;
while( i < M ) { uints[i] = ushorts[i]; ++i; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here an unrolled loop accessing in 64 bits chunks. It might be a little bit faster than the simple loop, but testing is the only way to know.

Assuming that N is a multiple of four, that sizeof (short) is 16 bit and working with 64 bit registers works.

```
 typedef union u {
     uint16_t    us[4];
     uint32_t    ui[2];
     uint64_t    ull;
 } u_t;
 ushort_t src[N] = ...;
 uint_t dst[N];

 u_t *p_src = (u_t *) src;
 u_t *p_dst = (u_t *) dst;
 uint_t i;
 u_t tmp, tmp2;
 for(i=0; i<N/4; i++) {
     tmp = p_src[i];    /* Read four shorts in one read access */
     tmp2.ui[0] = tmp.us[0];   /* The union trick avoids complicated shifts that are furthermore dependent on endianness. */
     tmp2.ui[1] = tmp.us[1];   /* The compiler should take care of optimal assembly decomposition. */ 
     p_dst[2*i] = tmp2;  /* Write the two first ints in one write access. */
     tmp2.ui[0] = tmp.us[2];
     tmp2.ui[1] = tmp.us[3];
     p_dst[2*i+1] = tmp2; /* Write the 2 next ints in 1 write access. */
 }
```

**EDIT**

So I just tested it on SUN M5000 (SPARC64 VII 2.5 GHz) with GCC 3.4.1 in 64-bit mode on a 4,000,000 element array. The naive implementation is a bit faster. I tried with SUNStudio 12 and with GCC 4.3, but I haven't been able to even compile the program because of the array size.

**EDIT2**

I managed to compile it now on GCC 4.3. The optimized version is a bit faster than the naive one.

```
              GCC 3.4          GCC 4.3
naive         11.1 ms          11.8 ms
optimized     12.4 ms          10.0 ms
```

**EDIT3**

We can conclude from that, as far as C is concerned, don't bother with an optimized version of the copy loop, the gain is so low that the risk of error outweighs the benefit.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
unsigned short src[N] = ...;
unsigned int dst[N];

for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
    dst[i] = src[i];
```

For a C++ version Konrad's or Nawaz's answers are surely better suited.

Comment: This ought to be the most efficient way in both C and C++, if we forget about compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize an `int[]` with the same length as the `short[]`.
2. Iterate over the `short[]`, assigning the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of the `short[]` to the  `i`<sup>th</sup> position of the `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

On many architectures a decrementing `do-while` may be faster than the `for` and `while` loops proposed here. Something like:

```
unsigned short ushorts[M];
unsigned int uints[N];

int i = M-1;
do{
    uints[i] = ushorts[i];
    i--;
} while(i >= 0);
```

The compiler can take care of most optimizations such as loop unrolling, but generally the above is faster (on many architectures) because:

- You get the first iteration for free in a `do-while` vs. a `while` or `for`
- The loop ends when i = 0. Checking for 0 can save an instruction because the zero flag is set automatically. If the loop incremented and ended when i = M then it may need an extra compare instruction to test if i < M.

There may be faster ways as well, such as doing it entirely with pointer arithmetic. This could turn into a fun exercise of disassembling the code and analyzing to see which appears faster. It is all architecture dependent. Fortunately others have done this work for you with std::copy.

Comment: The loop indices are wrong. It should be `int i = M-1` and `do {...} while(i > -1);`

Comment: While the loop termination might be slightly faster, copying backwards is equally likely not to be very cache friendly.

Comment: Since you're likely to be memory bound here, the extra ALU instruction to check the loop bound is unlikely to be a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the address of the short array to access each element of the short array, like `pTp32[0...LEN-1].arr[0..1]`:

```
unsigned short shrtArray[LEN]; //..
union type32
{
    short arr[2];
    int value;
};
type32 * pTp32 = (type32*)shrtArray;
```